# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on becomeFirstResponder call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have created a keyboard with some arrow keys that allows the user to navigate with arrow buttons, between all the text fields in the tableview.  (2 per cell)

There are some situations where cells will be disabled, so I have a recursive call to skip them.  ie.  if the user presses the right arrow, and the textField is disabled, recursively call the right arrow again to skip it.

I also animate any scrolling that needs to be done myself.  However, something has happened recently that is causing a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to set the firstResponder after a user navigates to a new textField, and the scrolling animation is finished.

I am able to reproduce this issue starting in the first cell and navigating down 2 times. Here is the code, in order of what is happening as best as I can display it, with a lot edited (like all the code for the other 3 arrow buttons so u only see the lines called)

```
//receive the arrow button pressed first

_arrowButton = arrowButton;
@try
{
    switch (_arrowButton.tag)
    {

        case NumericKeyboardViewDownArrow:
            destinationIndexPath =  [NSIndexPath  indexPathForRow:currentIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:currentIndexPath.section];
            newTag = currentTextField.tag;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

        // check bounds of the intended index path and return if out of bounds
    if ((destinationIndexPath.row == -1) || (destinationIndexPath.row >= [_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[destinationIndexPath section]])) {
        destinationIndexPath = currentIndexPath;
        return;
    }

    /* 
     Animation for scrolling
    */

    CGPoint current = [_tableView contentOffset];

    // if we must animate up
    if (destinationIndexPath.row < currentIndexPath.row)
    {
            // up code here
    }

    // if we must animate down
    else if (destinationIndexPath.row > currentIndexPath.row)
    {
        // always scroll animate for down
        [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, current.y + _tableView.rowHeight) animated:YES];
    }

    // if we only move left or right
    else
    {
            // left and right code here
    }

    //update our current location
    currentIndexPath = destinationIndexPath;
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    return;
}
```

then after the animation is finished in the did finish animating method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
 {
//after the animation is done, set the responder
nextTextFieldSelection = (UITextField *)[[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath] viewWithTag:newTag];
NSLog(@"nexttextfield%@",nextTextFieldSelection);
 if (nextTextFieldSelection)
 {
    //CRASH OCCURS HERE [nextTextFieldSelection becomeFirstResponder];
 }

[self checkTextFieldIsDisabled];
}
```

By the end of that method I am in a new text field and we check if disabled.  In reproducing this crash, it just exits because the textFields I am moving in to are not disabled.

Ive tried resigning the first responder before calling a new becomeFirstResponder but that doesn't seem to have any effect.  Its possible I wasn't resigning in the proper location though.  Any ideas where the memory issue would be?

Thanks

Comment: Seems likely that despite your check for exceeding the rows, that it is not working as you expect.
I can't tell much about how you are storing that value it could just be garbage by the time you attempt to use it. Perhaps set the responder before you try to animate to it.
Also, its probably far wiser for you to just enable and disable the button properly to prevent the user from performing erroneous actions, or actions that will do nothing when you prevent it in code.

Comment: Turn on zombies. Also what does your NSLog output prior to crash.

Comment: the NSLog prior to crash is `nexttextfield<BaseTextField: 0xc4f4650; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (581 9; 50 30); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+BM; tag = 1001; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xc4796d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xc4140b0>>`  or something similar

Comment: According to my NSLogs, the code checking the bounds of the table works fine.  The current index and destination index are all correct and the method exits appropriately.  Technically though, in order to reproduce this crash, i never need to access that code.  It should also be noted that this issue is a new one.  This functionality WAS working, but a few things were changed elsewhere and suddenly this issue appeared.  Most notably, the custom cell is calling a custom textField did begin/end editing delegate.  And i suspect this is possibly the cause but I dont know why, or if so, how to fix.

Comment: I turned on zombies (but im unfamiliar with it and don't know what to look for) and got this error instead: `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code = EXC_1386_BPT subcode = 0x0)`

Comment: ok, I think i may of found something.  The description of the error is a little more clear, and it states:  `*** -[MyCustomCell respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2e3b1590` which is the previous text field.

Comment: Its probably unsafe to keep references to things within table cells as the default implementation allows for reuse of cells. Regardless wether the code was correct after the users action it may not then be correct after the animation sequence where you are setting the responder.

Comment: I'd advise just setting the responder immediately after the user has made their action and you know which cell to activate. Then initiate your animation. There are so many edge cases that can appear in those sort of interactions, which you want to minimize or simplify.

Comment: I can't, because if the user is at the top of the visible rows, and they want to continue to scroll up, the textField to set first responder does not exist yet.  I have to scroll before I can set it.